# How to pause coroutines in Python?

Tags: python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have class like a Singleton for aiohttp Client Session. My code need to make responses with 1
session. Also i need to recreate session if they lifetime > 15 minutes. Sometimes, request A obtains a session and begins using it when its lifetime is 899 seconds, but request B also wants to obtain the session, causing it to be recreated. As a result, the first request fails with an exception and does not execute.
How can i do it?

```py
class Session:
    def __init__(self):
        self.session = None
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.create_task(self.create_session())
        self.last_created = datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()
        logger.info(f"Created session on {datetime.datetime.now()}")

    async def create_session(self):
        lock = asyncio.Lock()
        await lock.acquire()
        try:
            if self.session is not None:
                await self.session.close()
                logger.debug("Closing old session")
            self.session = aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=50), trust_env=True)
            payload = {
                "login": LOGIN,
                "password": hashlib.md5(PASSWORD.encode()).hexdigest()
            }
            async with self.session.post(f"{URL}/login", json=payload) as response:
                data = await response.json()
                if data['code'] == "0":
                    self.last_created = datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()
                    logger.debug(f"Logged in")
                    return True
        finally:
            lock.release()

    async def get_session(self):
        lock = asyncio.Lock()
        await lock.acquire()
        if datetime.datetime.now().timestamp() - self.last_created > 900 and not self.session._connector._conns:
            logger.debug(f"{datetime.datetime.now().timestamp() - self.last_created}, creating new session")
            await self.create_session()
            return self.session
        logger.debug(f"{datetime.datetime.now().timestamp() - self.last_created}, returning old session")
        lock.release()
        return self.session
```

I tried to use Lock, but it didn't help or i use it not correctly.

Also, i tried to check session._connector._conns, but sometimes i requests fails with an exception.

Comment: Sorry - from your description it is unclear for me what you want to achieve. Also, you did not include code to instante this class and get the async parts running, so it is not a complete example.

But I can advance you are using `Lock` incorrectly: the way it is in this code, your Locks are no-operations. The _same_ instance of a lock (in this case `asyncio.Lock` have to be tentatively acquired in all points that can not run concurrently. In this design you can make create your lock instance in the `__init__` method as an instance attribute, and use `self.lock.acquire()` where you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - re-reading your code and question I could figure out what you intend to do.

As stated in the comment, the major issue, if you want to follow this design, is that you are using `Lock` incorrectly: the *same* lock object have to be shared by everyone which will use a resource that should not run concurrently. As it is, you create a transient lock object inside your methods, and those will always succeed in been acquired.

You can rearrange your code more less like this:

```
import asyncio 
...
logger = ...
...

TIMEOUT = 900  # prefer to use "magic numbers" as constants in the beggining of files
               # so that the value is (1) easy to find; (2) modifed at once everywhere it is use
               # and (3) get a descriptive name

class Session:
    def __init__(self):
        self.session = None
        self.lock = asyncio.Lock()
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.create_task(self.create_session())
        self.last_created = datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()
        logger.info(f"Created session on {datetime.datetime.now()}")

    async def create_session(self):

        async with self.lock:
            if self.session is not None:
                await self.session.close()
                logger.debug("Closing old session")
            self.session = aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=50), trust_env=True)
            payload = {
                "login": LOGIN,
                "password": hashlib.md5(PASSWORD.encode()).hexdigest()
            }
            async with self.session.post(f"{URL}/login", json=payload) as response:
                data = await response.json()
                if data['code'] == "0":
                    self.last_created = datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()
                    logger.debug(f"Logged in")
                    return True


    async def get_session(self):
        # no lock use needed here: if there is a concurrent request, it will
        # be paused in "create_session"
        if (session_age:=datetime.datetime.now().timestamp() - self.last_created) > TIMEOUT and not self.session._connector._conns:
            logger.debug(f"{session_age}, creating new session")
            await self.create_session()
            return self.session
        logger.debug(f"{session_age}, returning old session")
        return self.session
```

However, while this will avoid a session to be created while other is being "get", it probably won't be of any use: whatever code got the session by calling `get_session` won't know about locks in this class, as it is - a second task needing the same sessions will just go through and the session in your class will be reset.

The way to keep the lock while your session is used by its clients is to implement yourself the  context manager protocol - so that your `Session` instance can be used with the `with` command: that can lock the session usage.
(Not sure if it would be of any use as well: because this will limit your usage to one request at a time - maybe you can have a session-pool instead, or think of another mechanism to renew sessions when needed)

```
import asyncio 
...
logger = ...
...

TIMEOUT = 900  # prefer to use "magic numbers" as constants in the beggining of files
               # so that the value is (1) easy to find; (2) modifed at once everywhere it is use
               # and (3) get a descriptive name

class Session:
    def __init__(self):
        self.session = None
        self.lock = asyncio.Lock()
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.create_task(self.create_session())
        self.last_created = datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()
        logger.info(f"Created session on {datetime.datetime.now()}")

    async def create_session(self):
        # lock now moved to "__aenter__" method.
        if self.session is not None:
            await self.session.close()
            logger.debug("Closing old session")
        ... # same code as in your example

    async def __aenter__(self):
        # no lock use needed here: if there is a concurrent request, it will
        # be paused in "create_session"
        try:
            self.lock.acquire()
        exception:
            logger.Error("could not acquire session lock")
        
        if (session_age:=datetime.datetime.now().timestamp() - self.last_created) > TIMEOUT and not self.session._connector._conns:
            logger.debug(f"{session_age}, creating new session")
            await self.create_session()
            return self.session
        logger.debug(f"{session_age}, returning old session")
        return self.session
    
    async def __aexit__(self, *args):
        self.lock.release()
```

Comment: hi, thanks, i think it got better, but now sometimes i get exception [Errno 1] [SSL: APPLICATION_DATA_AFTER_CLOSE_NOTIFY] application data after close notify (_ssl.c:2672). When i works with new session for each request, i didn't got it. Maybe u know how can i fix it?